# How to implement a magnifier in NSView

Tags: swift, swift3, nsview

I want to implement a magnifier in NSView that it's looks like preview.
I have some questions
1)Does it implements in NSView?
2)How to implement it?
3)How to let the magnifier over the View?
thanks for helping me
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually done this but I did it in objective-C.

it actually takes a bit of work to make it happen, but in short:

1. subclass NSImageView
2. in the subclass, you override, mouseEntered, mouseExited, and mouseMoved
3. in mouseEntered

---

```
NSPoint mouseLoc;
BubbleNSImage * magImg;
BubbleNSImage * magGlass;
mouseLoc = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow] fromView:nil];

// Setup the magnifying glass image
magGlass = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:
               [[NSImage imageNamed:@"magnifierCursor.png"] TIFFRepresentationUsingCompression:NSTIFFCompressionNone factor:0]];

// Get a 4x zoomed verion of a selection around where the mouse is
// set the image for the image view
if( 0 == _zoomMode ){
    magImg = [BubbleNSImage getPixelMultipliedNSImageRegionFromImage:self.image
                                                      withMultiplier:4
                                                        andSubRegion:NSMakeRect(mouseLoc.x - 17, 
                                                                                self.image.size.height - mouseLoc.y - 17, 
                                                                                34,
                                                                                34)]; 
}else{
    magImg = [BubbleNSImage getAppleMultipliedNSImageRegionNSImage:self.image
                                                    withMultiplier:4                                    
                                            andInterpolationMethod:_zoomMode     
                                                      andSubRegion:NSMakeRect(mouseLoc.x - 17,
                                                                              mouseLoc.y - 17,
                                                                              34,
                                                                              34)];
}


// Mask the 4x zoomed version with a mask made for the zoomer
[magImg maskWithImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"magnifierCursorMask.png"]
        andMaskOffset:NSMakePoint(0, 0)
         andMaskColor:[NSColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];

// Add the 4x zoomed image behind the magnifying glass image
[magGlass addImageBehind:(NSImage *)magImg
              withOffset:NSMakePoint(16, 16)
       clipToOrigImgSize:NO];

// Preseent the full image as the cursor
[[[NSCursor alloc] initWithImage:(NSImage *)magGlass hotSpot:NSMakePoint(83, 83)] set];
```

BubbleNSImage from the above code is a subclass of NSImage that allow me to perform a slew of operations on NSImages that aren't available with the standard NSImage object.  As you can see, it allows me to zoom using apple's different interpolators, as well as the addition of zooming using my personally written pixel replication.  It allows me to set the zoom multiplier, and the sub-region for which I wish to zoom.

Later it allows me to perform masking operation (this is useful as I was using a circular magnifier as well, and needed to clip outside of the circle.

It then allows me to perform overlay operations, where I take the clipped zoomed image and put it behind my magnifying glass image.

Finally, you need to initialize a new cursor object with the newly created image, then set it as the current cursor.

4. **This same code needs to be in your overloaded mouseMoved method.**
5. you need to set the cursor back to normal inside your overloaded mouseExited method

Objective-C code:

```
-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event{
    [[NSCursor arrowCursor] set];
}
```

there is quite a bit of example code out there for performing many of the image processing functions I have high level algorithmized above.